# Need python interface for moving a machine to another folder

Tags: python-2.7, virtual-machine, vsphere, pyvmomi, pysphere

I am trying to find a code support in `python` for moving a machine between Datacenter's folders without success, I saw in `pysphere` that you can define the folder just in the clone stage and not after machine already cloned.

[This](https://jackiechen.org/2011/11/01/moving-vm-to-folder-in-vcenter/) seems as a solution for my problem but it is in powershell, do anybody know a wrapping support for it in python

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with pyVmomi. I would avoid pysphere because pyVmomi is maintained by VMWare and pysphere hasnt been updated in 4 years or more.

That said here is some sample code that uses pyVmomi

```
service_instance = connect.SmartConnect(host=args.host,
                                        user=args.user,
                                        pwd=args.password,
                                        port=int(args.port))

search_index = service_instance.content.searchIndex
folder = search_index.FindByInventoryPath("LivingRoom/vm/new_folder")
vm_to_move = search_index.FindByInventoryPath("LivingRoom/vm/test-vm")
move_task = folder.MoveInto([vm_to_move])
```

In this example I create a `ServiceInstance` by connecting to a vCenter, next I grab an instance of the `SearchIndex`. The `SearchIndex` has several methods that can be used to locate your managed objects. In this example I decided to use the `FindByInventoryPath` method, but you could use any that will work for you. First I find the instance of the `Folder` named `new_folder` that I want to move my `VirtualMachine` into. Next I find the `VirtualMachine` I want to move. Finally I execute the `Task` that will move the vm for me. That task takes a param of the list of objects to be moved into the folder, and in this case its a single item list containing only the one vm I want to move. From here you can monitor the task if you want.

Keep in mind that if you use the `FindByInventoryPath` there are many hidden folders that are not visible from the GUI. I find that using the [ManagedObjectBrowser](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-50/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.wssdk.pg.doc_50%2FPG_ChB_Using_MOB.20.2.html) is very helpful at times.

Helpful doc links:

- https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi/blob/master/docs/vim/SearchIndex.rst
- https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi/blob/master/docs/vim/Folder.rst
- https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi/blob/master/docs/vim/Task.rst

Comment: This was extremely useful, thanks! Just for clarification for others finding this, `LivingRoom` in the above example is your Datacenter's name.

Comment: @Rekovni Yes. it seems.

Comment: @Michael-rice I can't seem to find the document links provided above? Are these documents that were linked above the same as [this](https://developer.vmware.com/apis/1355/vsphere)?