# Pyvmomi - Assign VM to specific folder with non-unique name

Tags: python-3.4, pyvmomi

I'm trying to figure out how to assign a VM to a folder that does not contain a unique name. I'm currently testing with the **clone_vm.py** template. With the sample, I have the ability to set the folder, but it does not work correctly if there's nested folders with the same name (example below). I would like to make sure the folder assigned is the "Linux/Dev" folder, but I can only pass "Dev" and hope that it picks the right one. The line of code below is how the folder is being set.

```
destfolder = get_obj(content, [vim.Folder], vm_folder)
```

Linux

```
    |------Dev

    |------Prod
```

Windows

```
    |------Dev

    |------Prod
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do that is to use a `search_index.FindByInventoryPath` and get the folder by the path. It can be a little confusing because of hidden folders but the MOB can help you. I answered a question where I covered how to use that search method see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41956255/need-python-interface-for-moving-a-machine-to-another-folder/41969205#41969205).

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for the suggestion. I used the FindByInventoryPath to grab the correct folder and everything works great.